# gulp-imagemin: Could not load default plugin `optipng`

Tags: javascript, изображения, gulp, npm, png

Пишет ошибку из заголовка в gulp.

Что было испробовано:

1. откат до версии 7.1.0
2. npm rebuild
3. npm удаление и снова установка
4. переход с require на import и прописыванием "type": "module" в package.json

Некоторое время откат до 7.1.0 работал (вроде), но сейчас точно не работает.

Есть еще идеи, как исправить? Миллионы людей пользуются, значит должно работать.